Twice differentiable at only one point?
We know the famous $x\mapsto x^2 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$ which is differentiable at just one point. But is it possible for a function to be twice differentiable only at one point, say $x = c$? For this, I understand that the function must be differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$ and thus continuous here.

If a function is differentiable at just one point, won't an antiderivative of that function be twice differentiable at just that one point?

@GerryMyerson and why does an antiderivative exist? The function $f(x)=x\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)$ doesn't have one for example, as it doesn't satisfy the mean value property, which all derivatives must do by Darboux's theorem

@AdamRubinson corrected.

What about the following? If $f(x)$ is a Weierstrass function, the presumably $xf(x)$ should be differentiable at $x=0$ only and it's antiderivative twice differentiable at $x=0$ only. Am I right? I made this a comment rather than an answer because I'm not sure.

@QuantumWiz by Weierstraß function do you mean one that is continuous but differentiable nowhere? If so you idea works perfectly you should write an answer.

@julio_es_sui_glace Thanks. However, it seems someone already gave that answer.

Let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb R$ that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.  Then $x^2 f(x)$ is again continuous everywhere and differentiable only at $x=0$.  Its antiderivative is $C^1$ everywhere and twice differentiable only at $x=0$.
For example, $f$ could be the Weierstrass function, or a sample path of a one-dimensional Wiener process
